# a databind dropdow- list

Tags: asp-classic

```
<html>
<body>
<%@ Language=VBScript  ENABLESESSIONSTATE = False%>
<form Name="sushant" method="post" action="sushant.asp">
<select id="selFiles" name="selFiles" class="Select" style="width: 250px" tabindex="130">

<% 

Dim fso, folder, files

Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

Set folder=fso.GetFolder("C:\")  

Set files=folder.Files    
For each folderIdx In files 

    Response.Write("<option>" + folderIdx.Name + "</option>")

Next  

 %>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying this code by giving its link in another file. but on execution IE shows an error in line set fso=Server.createobject..... i am  trying but i could not locate the error. can anyone help me out. sorry for the formatting issue.

Comment: What is the actual errorcode?

Comment: Server object, ASP 0177 (0x8007007E)
8007007e

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and it worked.  I don't think it's your code.  There must be something wrong on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll get that error if the system cant find the registerd object. Give

```
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\scrrun.dll
```

a go, and see if it sorts you out.

I've also seen the problem,specifically with the FSO, on a server with AV software that seemed to block it, so check this out too.